# Group By Works in JPQL Query, but doesn't work in DAOS

Tags: java, jpa

I'm having some troubles with a JPQL Query with a groupby, I'm making some tests with the JPQL Query from netbeans and works, but when I paste the same query in my Entity Manager the group by is ignored.

Can someone help me?

This is my JPQL Query result

[image: JPQL Query]
This is the Entity Manager result

[image: Entity manager result]

Comment: which query is printed in the console?

Comment: Is the same Query using em.createQuery